# Why is the layout of engine data different for CFM vs IAE engines on Airbuses?

Tags: airbus-a320, ecam

I do a fair bit of simulated flying in consumer flight simulators (and have no real-world flying experience or formal education). Recently, I started putting hours into a supposedly study-level A319 simulation with the option to use either CFM56-586 engines or IAE 2524-A5 engines, and besides some *very* subtle performance differences and visual changes to the exterior model, I noticed that the layout of the virtual gauges on the upper ECAM display is different between the two models:

- With CFM, the four data rows are (top to bottom) N1, EGT, N2, and FF, with no mention of EPR at all -- even if you select the `ENG` page on the lower ECAM.
- With IAE, top to bottom, EPR is prioritized, followed by EGT and N1, with FF and N2 off to either side.

This seems consistent across some other Airbus addons in my simulator, including an A320 which ships only with CFM engines, as well as an A330 which ships with only RR engines, but retains the IAE layout.

What motivates this layout difference, and why is EPR prioritized above other engine data on IAE (and apparently RR) engine configurations?